# How to extract the following strings from the file?

Tags: grep, string

Consider the following data (say located in file.txt):

```
P 5 24 0 0 -9.0786328019999996e+02 9.1141809916739828e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 22 0 0 -6 0
P 8 24 -3.9196518724924090e+00 2.0727804903086735e+00 -8.9632605571651516e+02 8.9993737237679568e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 44 0 0 -65 0
P 88 24 -4.2389618700766505e+00 1.2238515466784179e+00 -8.9698474520778257e+02 9.0059331315537133e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 62 0 0 -89 0
E 2 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 XXX
P 5 24 0 0 -6.7702324192000003e+02 6.8178272642703166e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 22 0 0 -6 0
P 8 24 -5.6932512713246979e+01 4.6556691594912991e+01 -6.3984521745934762e+02 6.4905928450035572e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 44 0 0 -9 0
E 3 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 YY
```

I.e. in general it has the form

```
P ..
...
P ..
E ..
P ..
...
P ..
E ..
```

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to make a file containing only the rows `P ..` just before `E ..`?

I.e. the file with

```
P 88 24 -4.2389618700766505e+00 1.2238515466784179e+00 -8.9698474520778257e+02 9.0059331315537133e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 62 0 0 -89 0
P 8 24 -5.6932512713246979e+01 4.6556691594912991e+01 -6.3984521745934762e+02 6.4905928450035572e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 44 0 0 -9 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` (since you tagged it with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)), and assuming we're using an implementation of the tool that has the non-standard `-B` option for extracting matching lines along with some number of preceding lines:

```bash
$ grep -B 1 '^E' file.txt | grep '^P'
P 88 24 -4.2389618700766505e+00 1.2238515466784179e+00 -8.9698474520778257e+02 9.0059331315537133e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 62 0 0 -89 0
P 8 24 -5.6932512713246979e+01 4.6556691594912991e+01 -6.3984521745934762e+02 6.4905928450035572e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 44 0 0 -9 0
```

This uses `grep` twice, first to extract all the lines starting with `E` and any line preceding these, and then to extract the lines starting with `P` from that.

The effect is that you will get those lines starting with `P` followed immediately by a line starting with `E`.

Redirect the output of the second `grep` to a file to save it in some file.

---

With `awk`, remember any line starting with `P` in the `pline` variable and printing (and clearing) it when we see a line starting with `E`:

```bash
$ awk '/^P/ { pline = $0 } /^E/ && length(pline) > 0 { print pline; pline = "" }' file
P 88 24 -4.2389618700766505e+00 1.2238515466784179e+00 -8.9698474520778257e+02 9.0059331315537133e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 62 0 0 -89 0
P 8 24 -5.6932512713246979e+01 4.6556691594912991e+01 -6.3984521745934762e+02 6.4905928450035572e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 44 0 0 -9 0
```

---

Using `sed` and assuming that `E` lines only occur by themselves, never in groups of two or more consecutive lines (if they do, you get the most recent `P` line outputted once per `E` line):

```bash
$ sed -e '/^P/ { h; d; }' -e 'g'  file
P 88 24 -4.2389618700766505e+00 1.2238515466784179e+00 -8.9698474520778257e+02 9.0059331315537133e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 62 0 0 -89 0
P 8 24 -5.6932512713246979e+01 4.6556691594912991e+01 -6.3984521745934762e+02 6.4905928450035572e+02 8.0419002445999993e+01 44 0 0 -9 0
```

This saves any `P` line to the hold space and starts the next cycle immediately.  If the line is not a `P` line, the most recently saved `P` line is fetched from the hold space and outputted.

(With the same assumptions, the `awk` code above could be shortened into `awk '/^P/ { pline = $0; next } { print pline }' file` which woulld be a literal translation of the `sed` code into `awk`)